How do I fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'?
This is the code:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'

from telegram.ext import CallbackContext
from telegram import Bot
import os

# Initialize your bot with the token from environment variable
bot_token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
if not bot_token:
    raise RuntimeError('BOT_TOKEN environment variable is not set.')

bot = Bot(bot_token)

# Messages for notifications
START_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS = " Work day: Notification system started! Get ready for a productive day ahead. "
END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS = " Job ended for today. Thank you for your hard work! See you tomorrow. "

START_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_STUDENTS = " Shuttle service is now available! You can start requesting rides. "
END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_STUDENTS = " Shuttle service has ended for today. See you again tomorrow! "

# Group ID intentionally removed
drivers_group_chat_id = -xxxxxxxxxx
pwd_group_chat_id = -xxxxxxxxxx

async def notify_workday_start_drivers(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await context.bot.send_message(drivers_group_chat_id, START_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS)

async def notify_workday_end_drivers(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await context.bot.send_message(drivers_group_chat_id, END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS)

async def notify_workday_start_students(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await context.bot.send_message(pwd_group_chat_id, START_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_STUDENTS)

async def notify_workday_end_students(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    await context.bot.send_message(pwd_group_chat_id, END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_STUDENTS)

I've deployed the bot to Heroku and when it gets to send the message I get the following error in the Heroku logs:
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043132+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043133+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base_py3.py", line 30, in run_coroutine_job
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043133+00:00 app[web.1]: retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043134+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043134+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/notifications.py", line 28, in notify_workday_end_drivers
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043135+00:00 app[web.1]: await context.bot.send_message(drivers_group_chat_id, END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS)
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043135+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043135+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043268+00:00 app[web.1]: 2024-06-16 23:07:00,043 - apscheduler.executors.default - INFO - Running job "notify_workday_end_students (trigger: cron[hour='23', minute='7'], next run at: 2024-06-17 23:07:00 UTC)" (scheduled at 2024-06-16 23:07:00+00:00)
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043293+00:00 app[web.1]: Context object: None

2024-06-16T23:07:00.043772+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043772+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base_py3.py", line 30, in run_coroutine_job
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043772+00:00 app[web.1]: retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043773+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043773+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/notifications.py", line 36, in notify_workday_end_students
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043773+00:00 app[web.1]: await context.bot.send_message(pwd_group_chat_id, END_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_STUDENTS)
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043773+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-16T23:07:00.043774+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bot'


you may want to go read this page about how to write your first bot.   you are missing a bunch of setup code, etc.   https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot

Somehow, the notify_workday_end_drivers() and notify_workday_end_students() functions were called with a null context argument.  We can't say any more than that, because you have not shown us how those functions are called.

@JohnGordon, I call them using apscheduler
scheduler.add_job(     notifications.notify_workday_end_students,     trigger='cron',     hour=00,  # Adjust the hour as per your requirement (e.g., 5 PM)     minute=35,  # Adjust the minute as per your requirement     id='workday_end_notification_students' )

async def notify_workday_start_drivers() -> None:
await bot.send_message(drivers_group_chat_id, START_WORKDAY_MESSAGE_DRIVERS)

I modified the functions to directly use the bot global variable instead of context. This removes the need for context as an argument and with this the problem was solved
